# Are the advantages of Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern worth the overhead?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

The question is stated in the subject: are the advantages of Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern worth the overhead?

In many cases, implementing the view model involves quite significant overhead of duplicating the Model properties and sometimes synchronization between Model and ViewModel data members. For example, currently in Silverlight 4 & WCF RIA, View Models are not generated (if the developer follows the MVVM pattern, it is up to him to create the view models, often duplicating the corresponding Model's properties at ViewModel, that do nothing significant but refer to Model as the storage).

Why not extending the Model class, providing additional properties to make it easy to be consumed by the View instead?

Answer (score 2):

> Why not extending the Model class, providing additional properties to make it easy to be consumed by the View instead?

Effectively that is what the [PresentationModel](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) is for. Which MVVM is strongly based on. The difference is that the ViewModel is the model for the view and not the model for the data. So you are concerned around more how the view behaves with the data.

If you have a simple UI that all it does is present the model then I would suggest expose the Model on a property of the ViewModel and bind to that. Make sure though the model does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc.

The power of the ViewModel is when you have things to do in response to a user action. The ViewModel can then support Commands, calling out to services and validation and thus leaving the Model as a data container

Comment: Why not simply extending the Model to contain the calculated properties customized for view, besides the raw data?

Comment: I agree with @Reed Copsey's comment about the same question. Then effectively you have a ViewModel and when you pass that further down into the domain/service layer it will have stuff on there that the domain will not understand, or care about and will confuse other developers

Answer (score 2):

> Why not extending the Model class, providing additional properties to make it easy to be consumed by the View instead?

In the simple cases, this is all the ViewModel is doing - wrapping up the Model so that its extended in a way that's consumable by the View.  If your Model can be bound directly, you're welcome to do so.

That being said, there is more to the ViewModel layer than just wrapping the model - this is also where the application specific logic - ie: the application's plumbing, will occur.  Something has to make the requests from the Model classes correctly and compose together the logic.

Comment: Why not simply extending the Model to contain the app logic besides the raw data?

Comment: @Dmitry: You're mixing concerns at that point - (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)  - Also, that ties your model to your specific application and usage.  The data portion, especially, can have a life outside of and beyond a specific application.

Comment: My model anyway has no meaning outside this single application. I also can understand the separation of concerns, but isn't at this case the price of it - having two hierarchies of data classes with synchronization  - too high?

Comment: @Dmitry: It all depends on the complexity of your app. I cannot even count the number of times I have started with the approach that you describe (binding to the model classes directly and sometimes extending them with a small number of simple properties), only to find that I later had to break it apart into viewmodels anyway since it just became too ugly as the complexity increased. So now I often bite the bullet and use viewmodels. I find that in the end of the day, it pays off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about extra work, you can always create a ViewModelBase (INotifyPropertyChanged , Errors/Validation, generic stuff) to be inherited by your ViewModel, it will minimize things that you think may cost you time to replicate. And also, Silverlight/Wpf provides us with binding which greatly reduces our coding, besides the fact that XAML also does that by providing functionalities through markup. Besides that you can further the design by using screens, controllers, etc.

For me, I do not see any "overhead" with regards to using MVVM; if there were, it'd be worth it. It properly deals with the Separation of Concerns. It provides a good platform for development especially in teams where people may take care of different aspects of the application without affecting other team members codes (especially between developers and designers).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Benefits of MVVM

1. Reduced complexity.
2. Isolation of Designing and Development.
3. Dependency injection.
4. Major advantage is when you have a Well MVVM structured Windows Phone application and want to develop same for Windows Metro Desktop, Only thing u want to concentarte on design as the same view model can be used as it is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Benefits of MVVM _"Reduced complexity"_ IMHO Using binding/commands/triggers etc makes the application way more complex _(to debug)_